# How to insert a newly created PHAsset at a specific position in camera roll?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, phphotolibrary

Is it possible to insert a new PHAsset to an appointed index in the camera roll?

I tried following:

```swift
let cam_req = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: camera_roll)
cam_req?.insertAssets([asset] as NSArray, at: IndexSet(integer: pos))
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Camera Roll is like a stack. It's sorted by import date. There is no way to change the order or to insert a photo/video at a specific position. If you want to do that you have to create a custom user album. Custom user albums contain references to the originals in the Camera Roll and can be reordered.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tapsmart.com/tips-and-tricks/album-order-reordering-photos-album-ios-12-guide/

> It’s important to note that this only works for custom photo albums you’ve created yourself – default albums like “All Photos” and “Favorites” are arranged chronologically and can’t be rearranged this way.

then it's impossible to change the order of “All Photos” and “Favorites” manually - on API level should also be limited.